# Custom validation message on 'type=url'

Tags: html, css

I am using `type=url` in my form to only allow a url to be passed through.

However, using the standard validation message is as follows [image]

Is there a way to change this? Here is the design what I am trying to achive (outline search bar, add message beneath, and make text in search box orange)

[image]

Here is function after my form

```
function searchIt() {

            let form = document.querySelector('form')
            console.log(form)

            form.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => {
             // onclick or the event that start the call
                interval = setInterval(() => {
                progress = progress >= 100 ? 100 : progress + 1
                document.getElementById('myprogress').style.width = `${progress}%`


            // end interval and wait at 100%
                if(progress == 100) clearInterval(interval);
                }, maxTime/100)
                document.getElementById('loadingcontainer').style.display = ""
                e.preventDefault()
                let urlIN = form.url.value
                let url = encodeURIComponent(urlIN)
                console.log(url)
                try {
                    const data = await fetch('/', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            url: url
                        })


                    }).then(res => {
                        document.open()
                        res.text().then(function(text) {

                            document.write(text)
                            // Hide the progressbar, stop the timer and reset progress
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        progress = 0;
                        document.getElementById('myprogress').style.width = "0%"
                        document.getElementById('loadingcontainer').style.display = "none";
    
                        });

                    })


                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                }

            })


        }
```

Comment: Hi again KyleUSA, you deleted your previous question and I had to adapt the answer I was in the middle of writing to this new question. Hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than write all the necessary validation for URLs, you can use the HTML5 [input type "url"](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url) in place of type "text", which has all that validation built in:

`<input type="url" name="location">`

That will require a properly formed URL, but `ftp://` is also proper.
You can further constrain it by using the
[`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute for your requirements *"beginning in http://, https://, includes www."*.

Here, using `novalidate` on the `<form_>` prevents the browser from showing it's own messages, then you can test a field's validity with `field.checkValidity()`

```js
const urlField = document.getElementById('onlyweb');
const messagebox = document.getElementById('errormessage');

document.getElementById('testform')
        .addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const valid = urlField.checkValidity();
            console.log('valid =', valid);
            if (valid) {
                messagebox.innerHTML = ''; // clear any message that might be there
                messagebox.classList.add('hidden');
            }
            else {
                messagebox.innerHTML = '<span class="errmsg">You need to include http:// or https:// and include the "www." prefix.</span>';
                messagebox.classList.remove('hidden');
            }
        });
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
div {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
#errormessage {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;
}
#errormessage.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="testform" action="#" novalidate>
<div>
Invalid fields will have a red border
</div>
<div>
  <label for="onlyweb">Only Web URLs</label>
  <input type="url"
         name="onlyweb" id="onlyweb"
         pattern="^https?://www\..*$"
         >
</div>
<div>
  <input type="submit" value="Test It">
</div>
<div id="errormessage" class="hidden">
</div>
</form>
```

I recommend just manipulating classes and writing CSS using the `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-selectors, rather than changing a bunch of `field.style.something=newvalue` which have to be coordinated to make sure you do & undo things consistently.
It also mixes style into your code, instead of keeping it in CSS where it belongs.

See MDN's [Client-side form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)
for [The Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#the_constraint_validation_api)
especially where it gives ["A more detailed example"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#A_more_detailed_example)

Comment: Hello again... question, I am trying yours and the form is still submitting. Any suggestions? I am using a POST action in form

Comment: @KyleUSA — the `e.preventDefault();` within the `.addEventListener('submit', ...` should prevent that — if you're set up the same. Another common approach is to hook a 'click' handler to the submit button, and in that case it is the click handler that should `e.preventDefault()`. If that doesn't do it, you should probably ask a new Question here. If you're using my approach I'd appreciate at least an upvote.

Comment: I just asked a new question. Info overload atm, and decided to start fresh. Thanks for all the help!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65946954/throw-warning-on-non-url-submission

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. However, you must create the validation yourself by attaching a `onsubmit` function to the form like so:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var expression = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var errorMsg = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
function val(){
  var value = input.value;
  if(regex.test(value)){
    input.style.borderColor="green";
    input.style.color="green";
    return true;
  }else{
    input.style.borderColor="red";
    input.style.color="red";
    errorMsg.style.display="block";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
#errorMessage{
  color:red;
  display:none;
}
.input{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
input{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2em;
    border-radius: 25px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form action="stackoverflow.com" onsubmit="return val()">
  <div class="input">
    <input>
    <p id="errorMessage">Yikes! That's not a valid URL.</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: the `type="url"` validates that the format is correct, so you don't need to do all that regex work yourself, you can just check the _validity_ of the field.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks for all this! However, the form would still submit.. Shoudn't the ```return false;``` stop this from doing so?

Comment: If it satisfies the regex, then we allow it to submit. I thought that was intended @KyleUSA

Comment: Yes but searching google.com which does not satisfy the regex, still allows it to submit which is not part of the regex

Comment: @KyleUSA I tested it in the snippet. It does not allow it to submit.

Comment: Okay, I will have to determine the error. Thank you so much!

Comment: Would it matter that I am using a POST request. It is still submitting on my machine

Comment: @KyleUSA It would not. Also, why did you unaccept the answer?

Comment: It stopped working for me all the sudden. I reset the server and now it does not work. I made minor tweaks to my code, which should not have impacted it

Comment: I also added a function that is after my form, if that is causing it to not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227979/discussion-between-spectric-and-kyleusa).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input type `url` and then check the validity using `.checkValidity()`.From Mozilla on the checkValidity method:  ***checks whether the element has any constraints and whether it satisfies them. If the element fails its constraints, the browser fires a cancelable invalid event at the element, and then returns false.***

It's also important to note that when one says URL validation, what exactly do they refer to when referencing a url? One could write in a url address bar, `www.stackoverflow.com` and they would end up at stackoverflows web site, however, the URL validation will require that the valid *protocol* ***http***, ***https*** is called in the `url` address in order to validate using an [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url#validation) `url` type. More info on `url` can be found here... [What is a URL? -Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)

```js
const input = document.getElementById("url");
const errorMessage = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
const validate = document.getElementById("validate");

validate.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (input.checkValidity() !== true) {
    input.className = 'false';
    input.classList.remove('true');
    errorMessage.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    input.className = 'true';
    input.classList.remove('false');
    errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

```css
#errorMessage {
  display: none;
  color: orange;
}

.true {
   border: 1px solid green;
   color: green;
}

.false {
   border: 1px solid orange;
   color: orange;
}

input#url {
  border-radius: .9rem;
  padding: .7rem; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form novalidate>
  <input id="url" type="url" required />
  <input type="submit" name="validate" value="Check" id="validate">
</form>
<p id="errorMessage">Yikes! That's not a valid URL.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer has been the best I have tried, however there is no outline that appears around the box, and the default CSS styling still shows up. Any thoughts?

Comment: ***however there is no outline that appears around the box, and the default CSS styling still shows up.*** Not sure what you mean about the default CSS styling still showing up. Try adding `input.classList.remove('defaultclass') within the conditional statements for pertinent logic. Open your inspector when the conditional returns false and when it returns true and see what classes are applied to the input tag and then add logic to remove that particular class.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your CSS in your question as well?

Comment: Hmm... the error warning shows up, but the standard CSS still appears. I am at a loss...
Here is my CSS for your reference. Any insight would be appreciated: https://pastecord.com/gigasocehi.css

Comment: Even if I cannot get an outline, just overriding  the default CSS is okay