# Custom validation message on 'type=url' to override standard CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

If a user does not search a url on the front end, I would like the design to appear as follows

[image]

Currently, this my form, which is using the `type="url"` to provide the validation without having to make a regex.

Here is a copy of my current form with a post request

```
<form action="POST" id="Submit">
                <div class="inner-form">
                    <div class="input-field first-wrap">
                        <div class="svg-wrapper">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z "></path>
                  </svg>
                        </div>
                        <input id="search" type="url" name="url" placeholder="Paste a domain here" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                        <button id="button" class="btn-search" onclick="searchIt()" value="press" type="submit">SEARCH       </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

and here is my script tag after the form

```
let progress = 0;
const maxTime = 5000; // 5 seconds
let interval = null;


    function searchIt() {

        let form = document.querySelector('form')
        console.log(form)

        form.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => {
         // onclick or the event that start the call
            interval = setInterval(() => {
            progress = progress >= 100 ? 100 : progress + 1
            document.getElementById('myprogress').style.width = `${progress}%`


        // end interval and wait at 100%
            if(progress == 100) clearInterval(interval);
            }, maxTime/100)
            document.getElementById('loadingcontainer').style.display = ""
            e.preventDefault()
            let urlIN = form.url.value
            let url = encodeURIComponent(urlIN)
            console.log(url)
            try {
                const data = await fetch('/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        url: url
                    })


                }).then(res => {
                    document.open()
                    res.text().then(function(text) {

                        document.write(text)
                        // Hide the progressbar, stop the timer and reset progress
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    progress = 0;
                    document.getElementById('myprogress').style.width = "0%"
                    document.getElementById('loadingcontainer').style.display = "none";

                    });

                })


            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err)
            }

        })



    }
```

How could I achieve the specified design in the mockup? I cannot seem to get this one for the life of me

Comment: Because of your use of `async` and `setInterval` the normal click and submit handling is taking place asynchronously with your code, so the submit is being processed without your `e.preventDefault()`  having any effect. You might want to split it into two functions — `form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault; callMyAsyncFunction(); })`

Comment: @StephenP The default `type=url` css is still showing up. Even if I don't have the outline, I just would like the default css to stop showing up

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- do you mean the browser-produced tooltip is still showing up? It would help if you turned the code in your question into a runnable stack-snippet.

Comment: Among other things, after your edit, you are not calling `searchIt()` until the submit "SEARCH" button is clicked, and then you attach the submit event handler. By then it's too late. You're already in the process of submitting the form, so your attempt to override the browser's handling of validation isn't even attached yet. In the "script tag after the form" you need to `let form = document.querySelector('form')` and `form.addEventListener('submit',...)` _outside_ of the `searchIt()` function, such as right after the line `let interval = null;`

Comment: Also, if you attach the submit handler as suggested, you don't need `onclick="searchIt()"` on your button at all. Inline event handlers are bad practice anyway — your markup (structure), presentation (CSS), and behavior (JS) should have clear separation (google "separation of concerns")

Comment: **OH!** -- and to prevent the default "Please enter a URL" you _must_ have the "novalidate" attribute on the form: `<form action="POST" id="Submit" novalidate>` — you might also want to work on your naming of things... the form's ID is "Submit" - maybe id="searchform" ... the button with ID "button" isn't descriptive, what does the button _do?_ It starts the search, so maybe `<button id="search" ...>`, renaming the URL field — and conventions generally discourage initial upper-case, so "search" not "Search"

Comment: And again, I'd separate out that `async(e) => { ... }` — you really only want to do that _after_ you've validated the input, displayed error messages, etc., and then only do it when you've decided that everything is valid and ready to be submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only part of your code that runs initially, on page load, are your three statements declaring your variables:

```js
let progress = 0;
const maxTime = 5000; // 5 seconds
let interval = null;
```

and the ***declaration*** of your `function searchIt()` — note that the function *is not being run*, it is only being declared, so the code *within* that function such as `form.addEventListener('submit', ...)` has not executed yet.

Meanwhile, you have a submit button with an inline event handler declared

```html
<button id="button" class="btn-search" onclick="searchIt()"
        value="press" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
```

so when "SEARCH" is clicked, *then* `searchIt` is run and the submit event-handler is attached, but by then it's too late — you're already in the process of submitting the form, so your attempt to override the browser's handling of validation isn't even attached yet.

In the "script tag after the form" you need to do `let form = document.querySelector('form')` and `form.addEventListener('submit',...)`
outside of the searchIt() function, *before* it is run, such as right after the line `let interval = null;`

In addition, the use of `async` directly on the event listener for the submit handler — `form.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => ...)` — makes the whole handler asynchronous, so the call in there to `e.preventDefault()` will likely not occur to prevent the default submit handling. The only part of the code you really want to be async is the `fetch()` and its handling of the fetch results. For that reason I would separate it into its own function so the submit handler becomes, in pseudo-code:

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        doValidation();
        if (it is valid) call the async function;
}
```

You mention in a comment that *"The default type=url css is still showing up."* — you need to tell the browser not to do its validation, by using the `novalidate` attribute on the form

```
<form action="POST" id="Submit" novalidate>
```

Finally, I would change the names used for some of the IDs to be more descriptive of the *purpose* of a thing; the button's ID is "button", which describes what the thing is, a button, but doesn't describe its purpose. What does that button do? It initiates the search, so maybe `<button id="search">` — while the field is where you enter the target URL you want to search, so `<input id="targeturl"...>`
I've changed several names in the example below.

---

Here's the page with the changes discussed. Note that with the "real" work encapsulated in a function you might want to move the maxTime, progress, and interval variables into that function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Kyle's URL field</title>
        <style>
        #errors {
            display: none;
        }
        #errors.has-error {
            display: block;
        }
        #errors #message {
            color: #e45b3f;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>

            <form action="POST" id="searchform" novalidate>
                <div class="inner-form">
                    <div class="input-field first-wrap">
                        <div class="svg-wrapper">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z "></path>
                            </svg>
                        </div><!-- svg-wrapper -->
                        <input id="targeturl" type="url" name="url"
                               placeholder="Paste a domain here"
                               required pattern="^https?://www\..*$"
                               >
                    </div><!-- input-field first-wrap -->

                    <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                        <button id="search" class="btn-search" value="press" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="errors">
                        <span id="message"></span>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- inner-form -->
            </form>

        </main>
    </body>

    <script>
    const maxTime = 5000; // 5 seconds
    let progress = 0;
    let interval = null;
    
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    const urlField = document.getElementById('targeturl');

    const errors = document.getElementById('errors');
    const message = document.getElementById('message');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('handling the form submit here');

        const valid = urlField.checkValidity();
        console.log(`valid = ${valid}`);

        if (valid) {
            clearError();
            console.log('about to run the async portion');
            doTheAsyncStuff(e);
        }
        else {
            console.log('twiddle with the DOM to display your custom error message');
            showError("Yikes! That's not a valid URL");
        }
    });

    function showError(msg) {
        message.innerText = msg;
        errors.classList.add('has-error');
    }
    function clearError() {
        message.innerText = '';
        errors.classList.remove('has-error');
    }

    async function doTheAsyncStuff(e) {
        console.log('now running the async function "doTheAsync"');
    }
    </script>
</html>
```